# Entity Framework "The member [...] does not exist in the metadata collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, datacontext

I got my different projects working and had to change a small thing in a model which forced me to drop my tables and re-create them. After a long period of researching I found out that I have to use Initializers (DropCreateDatabaseAlways). Additionally I created some custom Initializers to Seed my Database with Test data. Now every time I run my application I receive the following exception:

> The member with identity 'SGDB.DAL.Contexts.Person_Department' does
>   not exist in the metadata collection. Parameter name: identity.

Before I changed my model (has nothing to do with the relationship between Person and Department) everything worked fine. Additionally the identifiers of all my models are named Id (as EF expects) and are decorated with the [Key] attribute.

Yea, I already read other threads about this topic but the solution there was to create a Id Property for every foreign key (in my case DepartmentId in Person.cs) but I don't like that - especially because I know it worked before.

What could be the cause?

**Update 1:**

I'm trying to seed new Persons as following:

```
protected override void Seed(PersonContext context) {
        base.Seed(context);
        var dep = new DAL.Contexts.DepartmentContext().Departments.First();

        var status = new Status {
            StatusType = "Test"
        };

        var persondata = new PersonData {
            Status = status
        };
        context.Status.Add(status);
        context.PersonData.Add(persondata);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var person = new Person {
                Firstname = $"TestPersonFirstname{i}",
                Lastname = $"TestPersonLastname{i}",
                SourceType = COM.SourceType.Manual,
                Department = dep,
                PersonData = persondata
            };
        context.Persons.Add(person);
        }


        context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My issue was related to a "instead of insert" trigger on one of my tables.

The EF framework is performing validation on the inserted row of data by calling scope_identity().  However, an "instead of insert" trigger will change the context of the insertion in such a way that the EF system's call to scope_identity will return null.

You can do some of these:

1. Remove the instead of insert trigger (worked for me).
2. Turn off validation in the EF framework       context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; (this also
   worked)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Turning off the Validation didn't solve my problem. How does your first mentioned solution-attempt work? I'm pretty new to EF - I'm seeding a new Department into the DB and calling this dataset when seeding a new person (var department = new DepartmentContext().Departments.First();) - or could this be the problem? If so - how should I retrieve the data from the database to insert a new person?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also and it was fixed by adding the code below to the end of the instead of insert trigger.

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS <IdFieldName>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an insert trigger issue.

SQL Code with an outputting select statement, used for debugging, remained in an insert trigger.

Commenting out the offending select statement in the trigger resolved the issue.